# nlminb in R returns a value of -Inf for the objective function

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, convergence

**Note**
Unfortunately I'm not in a position to provide a reproducible example since I have a rather large code segment. I don't think it's a good idea to paste 300+ lines of code so I have provided a skeleton and some pseudo-code to try and explain the problem.

**Problem**
I am working on an optimization problem in R using `nlminb`. The
optimizer has worked quite well except for one particular data set with my objective function. The following provides some context about the problem (with syntax simplified).

```
# Function with parameters to optimize
#
# my_function = function(params, additional_values1, additional_values2, data){
#      Perform calculations
#      return(value)
# }

# init = vector of initial values
# my_data = relevant data
#
> optimize = nlminb(init, my_function, 
                    additional_values1 = matrix1, additional_values2 = matrix2, 
                    data = my_data, hessian = T)
> optimize
$par
[1] -2.367386  3.032712 -1.146100  3.620519

$objective
[1] -Inf

$convergence
[1] 0

$iterations
[1] 5

$evaluations
function gradient 
       8       24 

$message
[1] "X-convergence (3)"
```

The convergence of 0 suggests that the optimizer has converged, however the objective function returns a value of `-Inf`.

Is it possible to set a lower bound on the objective function, or get `nlminb` to provide the last real value of the objective function (along with the corresponding parameter values)?

I have tried playing around with the `control parameters` of `nlminb` however I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a reproducible example. You could check in your objective function whether the returned value will be `-Inf`, and then perhaps have the function report the parameters or debug the function in some other way.

In general, convergence merely means that some stopping criterion has been satisfied; so you should not trust it too much:

```
nlminb(c(0, 0), function(x) -Inf)
## $par
## [1] 0 0
## 
## $objective
## [1] -Inf
## 
## $convergence
## [1] 0
## 
## $iterations
## [1] 1
## 
## $evaluations
## function gradient 
##        2        2 
## 
## $message
## [1] "X-convergence (3)"
```

Comment: It's difficult to produce a reproducible example since the code is long, complicated and somewhat proprietary. I don't think it's a good idea to paste 300+ lines of code for a reproducible example. The code + pseudocode given above should be sufficient to convey the problem,